# Data protocol specification used in mobile and web applications

Tags: facebook, url, mobile, protocols

I'm working on developing a Facebook promotion for a mobile operator and I'm wondering where to get the following information:

1. Data protocol specification used in mobile and web applications
2. All URLs or similar of each data protocol.
3. If the above information is updated or whenever there are changes,
   updates or new versions, how could I be notified or where to check it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`data`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) is not a protocol but [URL Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

Notes on Browser Support of `data` URL scheme can be found on http://dataurl.net/#browser
You really need to read Wikipedia article about [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and follow references and links.